# Lifespan of mapper class instance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

A mapper class instance will be created and used for one InputSplit (or a mapper task)? Or multiple mapper class instances can be handling one InputSplit (or a mapper task)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each input split is handed to a mapper, and a mapper will only process a single input split.

However if you have mapper speculative execution turned on, then a input split can be run by two mappers on different nodes in parallel (there are certain conditions that will trigger speculative execution, you should be able to google them).

Also, if a map task fails, then the input split will be scheduled to run on another cluster node as another map task.